# Fine-tuning and monitoring a Spring cache backed by a ConcurrentMapCache

Tags: caching, spring-cache

I have set up a Spring cache manager backed by a **`ConcurrentMapCache`** for my application.

I am seeking for ways to monitor the cache and especially make sure the data in cache fits in memory. I considered using **jvisualvm** for that purpose but there might be other ways... If so what are they?

So my question is basically twofold:

- What is the best way to monitor a cache backed by a **`ConcurrentMapCache`**?
- What are the general guidelines for setting the **time to live** and **cache size** values of a cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are searching for cache related features that can't and won't be available with a "simple" map implementation provided by the JVM.

There are many cache providers out there that provides what you want, that is monitoring, limiting the size of the cache and providing a TTL contract for the cache elements. I would encourage you to look around and switch your `CacheManager` implementation which will have zero impact on your code since you're using the abstraction.